# Group database table data and load into c# objects

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

My database table will be generated as a DLL (consists of datatables and rows) and I wanted to group the data based on ID and load into the Student class.

What is the best way to group these in C# code? Do I need to use plinq or parallel.foreach?

Database Table Rows

```
FName   ID  Cors    Hour
John    1   Math    20
John    1   Lab     30
John    1   Tax     10
Rudy    10  TV      5
Rudy    10  Tech    10


public class Student
{
public string Name { get; set;}
public string ID { get; set;}
public Course Courses { get; set;}
}

public class Course
{
public string Code { get; set;}
public string Hours { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: What do you even mean by "table will be generated as a DLL"? Anyway, try providing some code that you're stuck with, explaining the problem that you're having, and asking a more concrete question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Linq extension methods, grouping of a sequence could be done with [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).